# CDL.toJSONArraynot build JSON Array in Java

Tags: java, json, csv

I have CSV data which look like this:

```
Name,Title,Class,Users
Global D&A,W,clLevel,"ADMIN"
Template Manager,X,clLevel,"G,ADMIN"
Test Manager,W,clLevel,"G,ADMIN"
```

I'm trying to convert it to JSON in Java, however with no success. My code is:

```
String dataIn = ///data input correct ///
JSONArray pageArr = CDL.toJSONArray(dataIn);
System.out.println("Conversion");
System.out.println("length: "+pageArr.length());
System.out.println("Data: "+pageArr.toString());
```

I have confirmed that the 'datain' is correct. And the terminal prints 'Conversion' yet fails to print 'pageArr.length()' or do any of the JSONArray methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if your data was really correct, try with a dataIn with no " or , characters.

For instance can you run

```
  String test = "Name,Title,Class,Users\nGlobal D&A,W,clLevel,\"ADMIN\"";
  System.out.println(CDL.toJSONArray(test));
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example does work.  However with my data is does not. I'm saving the csv from excel and reading it in. When I print the correct java formatted string and 'test' and my data in the console they both look similar. Any idea if excel adds weird EOL or EOF formatting that won't appear in the console?

Comment: Excel included a carrage retrun cahracter and that screwed up the toJSON somehow.. Prime the data before use. 'dataIn = dataIn.replaceAll("\\r", "");'